# IIS 7 removes Content-Disposition filename for Content-Type application/pdf

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, pdf

I have the following code that returns a PDF file in my web application:

```
string path = "help.pdf";
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", data.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=help.pdf");
Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
Response.End();
```

When I call the handler of this code in any browser (Chrome, IE or Firefox), I get a "Save as..." dialog with the name of the page (`index.aspx`) rather than the name provided in the code (`help.pdf`).

I checked the HTTP response header with all browsers. It looks like this:

```
Cache-Control:private
Content-Disposition:attachment
Content-Length:89407
Content-Type:application/pdf
Date:Thu, 07 May 2015 08:43:12 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-UA-Compatible:IE=edge,chrome=1
```

As you can see the filename parameter is removed from the Content-Disposition field. So the behaviour of the browser is correct. The web server (IIS) seems to tinker around with the header.

I found somebody with the same problem [here](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/508954-addheader-content-disposition-has-no-effect). But the problem was never solved. Any ideas?

**Note:** Modifiyng the code is not a solution. We have third party controls (Telerik RadGrid) on the site that have the same problem with their "Export to PDF" feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that because of an [IIS 7.5 issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/979543) someone added the following lines to the `web.config` file of the application:

```
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="Force pdfs to download" preCondition="only match pdfs">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Content_Disposition" pattern="(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="attachment" />
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="only match pdfs">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^application/pdf" />
        </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
</outboundRules>
```